# private key should be a Buffer

Tags: web3js

I need to check the balance of several addresses for the presence of erc20 tokens, if the balance is not empty, send eth there and forward this balance to the resulting address. But in the end, I get an error: `private key should be a Buffer` on the line `transaction.sign (keys [k])`

```
let foreth = ["addr1", "addr2"];
let keys = [Buffer.from('keyaddr1', 'hex'),Buffer.from('keyaddr2', 'hex')]

foreth.forEach(async function(recipient, i) {
    const balance = await contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(recipient).call(function(err, result) {


        if (result > 0) {


                web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)
                    .then((count) => {
                        let rawTransaction = {
                            'from': fromAddress,
                            'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
                            'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000),
                            'to': recipient,
                            'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("0.0002")),
                            'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count + i)
                        }

                        let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
                        transaction.sign(privateKey)
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
                                .on('transactionHash', console.log)
                                .on('receipt', resolve)
                                .on('error', reject)
                        })
                    }).then(receipt => {
                        console.log("status success")
                        for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                         web3.eth.getTransactionCount(recipient)
                        .then((count) => {
                            let rawTransaction = {
                                'from': recipient,
                                'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
                                'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(200000),
                                'to': tokenAddress,
                                'value': 0x0,
                                'data': contract.methods.transfer(fromAddress, web3.utils.toHex(result)).encodeABI(),
                                'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(count+i)
                            }
                            let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
                            transaction.sign(keys[k])
                            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
                                .on('transactionHash', console.log)

                            .on('error', console.log)   

                        })    
                    }
                    })

        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var privateKey = Buffer.from('abcde', 'hex')

let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
transaction.sign(keys[k])
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
...
```

To this:

```
var privateKey ='abcde'

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey).then(signedTx => {
           web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx);
    ...
})
```

Comment: error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: privateKey.startsWith
is not a function

Comment: @Ayurpwnz: You should be more specific (also in your question), and indicate exactly which line of code gives you this error. If you're not sure, then please debug your code and find out. The fix that I suggested is for the last part in your code, there could be other fixes required as well.

Comment: so I wrote: error: private key should be a Buffer on the line `transaction.sign (keys [k])`

Comment: @Ayurpwnz: And I explained that you should get rid of that line. Have you missed that in my answer???

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, the error with your fragment is in the modules:   `(C: \ Users \ Admin \ node_modules \ web3-eth-accounts \ src \ index.js: 220: 28
)
    at C: \ Users \ Admin \ node_modules \ web3-eth-accounts \ src \ index.js: 272: 16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal / process / task_queues.js: 93: 5)
(node: 9316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch (). (rejection
 id: 44)`

Comment: can u help me plz?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz: Not when you dump your errors on me like this. Please split your code into smaller segments, and then work them out one by one. I gave you a solution for the last part of your code, but you have a similar part at the beginning of your code, so try to apply a similar solution there too. In general, you should debug your code step by step, find out exactly which line is throwing an error, and then post the **smallest** segment of code which reproduces that error. In your question (as well as in the comment above), you are doing the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var transaction_data = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey = Buffer.from('abcde', 'hex')

        var transaction = new Tx(transaction_data,{ chain: 'ropsten' , hardfork: 'petersburg' });

        transaction.sign(privateKey);

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash', console.log);
```

to the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var transaction_data = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey ='abcde'

        web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction_data, privateKey)
        .then(function(value){
            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(value.transaction_data)
            .then(function(response){
              console.log("response:" + JSON.stringify(response, null, ' '));
            })
          })
```

`web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` will take the burden of including the correct chainId and nonce .
Reference: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/1040